# Java RMI implements interface

Tags: java, rmi

Hello all I have an assignment to make an RMI application that opens and reads a file residing on a remote server. I think I have everything I need (aside from the interface methods, which I can write later) but the main specification of the assignment is that there must be only **two** files which I have named **RMIFileServer** and **RMIFileClient**. Meaning that the interface must be written and implemented in the same file as the **RMIFileServer**(This leads to the problem). I must implement the interface no different than this.

```
public interface RemoteFileObject extends Remote{
    
    public abstract void open(String fileName) throws RemoteException;

    public abstract String readLine() throws RemoteException;

    public abstract void close() throws RemoteException;
}
```

**RMIFileServer.java** (sorry for formatting, have not figured out how to post code correctly here yet)
Right now I am implementing just the **readLine()** method of the interface to test that the RMI is even working.

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;

public class RMIFileServer extends UnicastRemoteObject {

// default constructor throwing RemoteException
public RMIFileServer() throws RemoteException{};

// interface definition
public interface RemoteFileObject extends Remote{
    
    public abstract void open(String fileName) throws RemoteException;

    public abstract String readLine() throws RemoteException;

    public abstract void close() throws RemoteException;
}

// inner class for interface implementation 
class Impl implements RemoteFileObject {
    public void open(String fileName) throws RemoteException{
    
    }

    public String readLine() throws RemoteException{
        return "From Server";
    }

    public void close() throws RemoteException{
    
    }
}

// creation of the server
public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException , AlreadyBoundException{
    try{
        RMIFileServer fileServer = new RMIFileServer();
        
        // remote object stub for interface methods
        RemoteFileObject stub = (RemoteFileObject) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(fileServer,0);
        
        // register the remote object with RMI registy 
        Registry registy = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
        registy.bind("RemoteFileObject", stub);
        
        System.err.println("Server ready");
        
        }
        catch (java.io.IOException ioe){
            throw new RemoteException("IO Exception",ioe);
            }
   }
}
```

**RMIFileClient.java**

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;

public class RMIFileClient{

public static void main(String[] args){
    
    String host = (args.length < 1) ? null : args[0];
    try{
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(host);
        
        RMIFileServer.RemoteFileObject stub = (RMIFileServer.RemoteFileObject) 
        registry.lookup("RMIFileServer.RemoteFileObject");
        String response = stub.readLine();
        System.out.println("Response: "+ response);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.err.println(e);
        }
   }
}
```

The files compile fine. When attempting **rmic RMIFileServer**

**I get the following error** "Stubs are only needed for classes that directly implement an interface that extends java.rmi.Remote; class RMIFileServer does not directly implement a remote interface."
I understand that this means the **RMIFileServer** must implement the interface but as I said I can not have a separate file to implement the interface. It must be defined and implemented within the **RMIFileServer** class. The error resides in the **RMIFileServer** main method where a new class object is instantiated. What can I do to fix this?

Thank you for reading this far, I appreciate your time.

Comment: To anyone reading this now I just had to change the Impl class in the server to static. But how would one clear the registry? It ran once but now throws already bound exception

Comment: Try method `rebind` instead of method `bind`.

Comment: Abra Thank you. This worked

Comment: The instruction to put the remote interface inside the remote server implementation file is poor practice, and you can tell them I said so. It needs to be separate so it can be easily shared with and deployed to the client. Author *java.rmi: the Guide to Remote Method Invocation,* Addison Wesley 2001.

Comment: You don't need to use `rmic` unless you are running a very old JVM (before 1.5).